# Tutte polynomial

Tags: graph-theory

I am asked to find the Tutte polynomial of $K_4 − e$ by definition of  Tutte polynomial and  delete-contract definition respectively.

I have calculated and i get

$K_4 = x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 4xy + 2y + 3y^2 + y^3$

which should be correct.

But how can i relate that with $K_4 − e$?

And for the second bit with the delete-contract definition bit, from my lecture note i get

polynomial of $K_3$ = polynomial of $K_3-e$ + polynomial of $K_3/e$.

Are there any way i can find the polynomial of $K_3/e$?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article [Tutte polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial) section on contraction-deletion?

Answer (score 1):

## direct definition

Definition. For an undirected graph $G=(V, E)$ one may define the Tutte polynomial as
$$
T_G(x, y)=\sum_{A \subseteq E}(x-1)^{k(A)-k(E)}(y-1)^{k(A)+|A|-|V|},
$$
where $k(A)$ denotes the number of connected components of the graph $(V, A)$. In this definition it is clear that $T_G$ is well-defined and a polynomial in $x$ and $y$.

## delete-contract definition

From the wikipedia,

The deletion-contraction recurrence for the Tutte polynomial,
$$
T_G(x, y)=T_{G \backslash e}(x, y)+T_{G / e}(x, y), \quad e \text { not a loop nor a bridge. }
$$

**watch out! where $e$ can not be a loop nor a bridge.**

[image]

**I only plot part of the tree, but that's enough**.
In the large tree,the Tutte polynomial of a node $V$ is 【sum of all of the Tutte polynomials of the leaves given that the node $V$ being set as root】